# How to use Jmeter variable into JSON path expressions - JSON Extractor?

Tags: jmeter

For example, my query is `$._data[?(@.label == 'IssueID' )].id` now in place of `'IssueID'` i want to use the jmeter variable like `$._data[?(@.label == ${IssueID} )].id` or `$._data[?(@.label == '${IssueID}' )].id`.

It returns only the default value of JSON Extractor not from the json.

Tried the above query with default value from JSON instead of Jmeter variable. It works fine there is no issue in query only think is i need to use Jmeter Variable in it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both are wrong, you should be using the following syntax:

```
$._data[?(@.label == '${IssueID}' )].id
```

You basically need to replace the hard-coded value of `IssueID` with the equivalent [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) and the substitution will happen in the runtime.

You can observe JMeter Variables along with their respective values using [Debug Sampler and View Results Tree listener combination](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script)